# Is this a constructor declaration?

Tags: c#, class, oop, methods, constructor

I am new to C# language and came across this kind of declaration in a website. I haven't seen this type of constructor(?) before, so I was really confused:

```
  public class Employee { 

  public string Name { get; set; } 
  public string Title { get; set; }  

  public static Employee GetEmployee() {          //Constructor? Method?
     var emp = new Employee() { 
        Name = "Somebody", Title = "Developer" 
     }; 
     return emp;                                  //Returns to a method?
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It isn't a constructor. Just a static method

Comment: Another name for this would be `factory method` if you are interested in Design Patterns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Constructor? Method?
```

Method. A static method.

This pattern is commonly used in conjunction with a *private* constructor:

```
public static Employee GetEmployee()
{
    return new Employee()
    { 
        Name = "Somebody", Title = "Developer" 
    }; 
}

private Employee() { }
```

The private constructor ensures that an instance of the class can *only* be created by using one of the static methods.

Such a "factory method" is more flexible than a constructor:

- It can return an instance of a subclass (often used with private, inner subclasses),
- it has a name, which can increase readability and allows you to have multiple factory methods with the same parameter list but different names (such as `GetDeveloper()` and `GetManager()`).

However, it also has a drawback: You can only set `readonly` fields in a constructor. Thus, if `Employee` were an immutable class with readonly fields, you'd need to pass all values to the private constructor when using this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a constructor but just a normal static method.

```
public class Employee 
{ 
    //Default constructor
    public Employee()
    {
        Name = "Some other name";
        Title = "Some other title";
    }

    //Static constructor
    static Employee()
    {

    }

    //Just a static method returning an Employee object
    public static Employee GetEmployee() 
    {      
        //Object initializer using the default constructor   
        var emp = new Employee() 
        { 
            Name = "Somebody", 
            Title = "Developer" 
        }; 
        return emp;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're asking about the object initializer. It's not a constructor, but the static method calls the default constructor and then uses object initializer syntax to set two properties on the new object.

If you had to name the method, you'd call it a factory method. There's nothing special about the method, it's just a static method that returns a new object instance. It happens to implement a common software pattern known as the factory pattern.

There are a few common uses for the factory pattern. One example that came up recently for me was sometimes I wanted to make a new object instance and sometimes I wanted to return an existing instance. The factory pattern supports that in a way that is transparent to the caller. Another common use is when the caller doesn't know the specific type being created - the caller may only need a reference to an interface or a base class and the factory decides the specific class to instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

what you are seeing in the code pice is a simple static function, that create an instance of the object, though for it to be complete , is should hide the abbilty to create an Employee object , by making the constructor private because the default behavor of the constructor is to be public

> If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default
> instance constructor is automatically provided. That default
> constructor simply invokes the parameterless constructor of the direct
> base class.

from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)